# Navigation in a class second after registry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying navigate beteween screens but I dont know how to navigate after the first screen. This wuestion is also about navigation on class, because all of the examples shows only props inside constants.

file: index.android.js

```
const AppNative = props => {
 return <AppScreen navigation={props.navigation} />;
};
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator( {
  Home: { screen: AppNative },
  Register: { screen: Register },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent("AppNative", () => MyApp);
```

file: App.js

```
const AppScreen = props => {
  const { navigate } = props.navigation;
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        navigation={props.navigation}
        onPress={() => navigate("Register")}
        title="Cadastrar com email"
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default AppScreen;
```

file: Register.js

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    //??????
    const RegisterNav = DrawerNavigator({
      Register: { screen: Register },
      OtherScreen: { screen: OtherScreen },
    });
    return (
        <View>
            //??????
            <Button onPress={() => navigate("OtherScreen")}>
            Entrar
            </Button>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
export default Register;
```

Nothing happens when I click on button in the file Register.js

Dependencies (package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "apsl-react-native-button": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
},
```

Comment: Need I declare all of my screens on the js that has my registry?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to navigate inside `RegisterNav` but the navigate method belongs to your `MyApp` navigator.

It should work if you declare all your screens in the same navigator.

```
const MyApp = DrawerNavigator( {
  Home: { screen: AppNative },
  Register: { screen: Register },
  OtherScreen: { screen: OtherScreen },
});
```

Comment: Should I have only navigator for all app?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can also have nested navigators (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting), if you want to navigate from outside the navigator don't forget to pass down the `navigation` prop `<RegisterNav navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Comment: Not sure if it works with drawer navigators, the documentation is only about StackNavigator containing a TabNavigator